# UITableViewCell - selected background size based on content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have this code to get table cell

```
func getCell(_ tableView: UITableView) -> UITableViewCell? {
     var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CELL_REUSE_ID)

     if (cell == nil)
     {
        //init and configure the cell
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: CELL_REUSE_ID)

        let selectedView:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell!.frame.size.width, height: cell!.frame.size.height))
        selectedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.3)

        let layer = selectedView.layer
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = getCellBorderWidth();
        layer.cornerRadius = getCellCornerRadius();
        layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        cell!.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView
     }

     return cell
 }


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell:UITableViewCell? = getCell(tableView)

        cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        cell!.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.darkText
        cell!.textLabel!.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
        cell!.textLabel!.textAlignment = .right
        cell!.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 1
        cell!.textLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

        return cell!
    }
```

Cells and table are generated in code, no xibs. Now, If I select cell, the background is covering entire width of table. How can I do background for some cells, that is only half of the table width (or some other percentual ratio)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think U can add another view to `selectedBackgroundView`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        // selectedBackgroundView
        let backgroundView = UIView()
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0)
        // add another view to selectedBackgroundView, and set any frame for this view
        let selectView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 40))
        selectView.backgroundColor = .red
        backgroundView.addSubview(selectView)
        cell?.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView
    }

    return cell!

}
```